# Recommended way to access DB2 from .net

Tags: .net, db2, cobol

We are designing a system that will access DB2 databases from .Net.

There appear to be 3 ways to do this:

- Dynamic SQL
- Stored Procedures
- CICS

One benefit of using dynamic SQL, would be to remove the need of having a Cobol programmer on the team. Is this correct?

Which one would you recommend? Are there other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any reason you would design a new .NET system with a CICS data access layer. I would definitely at least use ADO.NET (which what I think you mean by dynamic SQL?). IBM has an ADO.NET data provider available for DB2 with implementations for IDbConnection, IDbReader, etc.

I believe [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate) also supports DB2 UDP, so you may want to look into that as well.

Comment: If the data is stored on a z/OS box, accessing it via a CICS web service provides a nice layer to interject business logic, data validation and security.

Comment: Does a CICS layer really provide any advantage over keeping it all in .NET? I work around a z/OS box everyday, and I generally try to stay in the .NET world. Would a CICS layer provide any performance enhancements over .NET?

Comment: The .NET world is nowhere near as reliable as the z/OS world for data.  Speed and reliability are both improved if you put most of your back end on z, and your hardware costs are should be lower.  All of that assumes a sufficiently large system though.  You wouldn't want to go the z route if you only had a small system, say a few million transactions a day or something.  But once you get into larger systems, hundreds of millions tps+, the hardware and setup costs of one z box and some CICS regions are dwarfed by cost of the dozens of high end windows servers you need for that workload.

Answer (score 3):

.NET can connect to DB2 the same way it can connect to other databases.  Try DB2Connect.

Comment: Is DB2Connect something that exists? I cannot find such a thing installed on Windows, with SQL Server, or available for download anywhere.

Comment: DB2Connect is a product from IBM.  If you have DB2, your DBAs should be able to point you to where to get the jars for it.

Comment: I don't have DB2, and the customer with DB2 is asking *me* where to get it.

Comment: Also, it is possible to set up an ODBC connection to DB2, so you could connect that way as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to favour Store Procedures, it should be faster and more maintainable than Dynamic SQL and less coding than CICS/

**Dynamic Sql:**

- **Pros:** Faster development, Familiar to .net developers
- **Cons:** Sql is not centrally maintained in DB. You can not query DB2 for usage of tables, find where database are updated.
     Sql is anaylsed when used, leading to higher processing

**Sql Procedures**

- **Pros:**

  ```
   - Faster SQL execution
   - DB2 has control of SQL, you can query DB2 getting paths used by the 
   - SQL, Finds where tables / fields are used and updated
   - SQL is analysed at "Bind" time rather than execution time
     (normally when the program is compiled).
     This leads to lower overheads and consistent execution times.
   - Your SQL is vissible to DBA's, (Mainframe ?) developers
  ```
- **Cons:** May need  (Mainframe ?) developers

**Cics**
 - **Pros:**

```
    - All the advantages of SQL Procedures
    - Can access VSAM Files
    - Can buffer Common SQL in TS Queues, TD Queues, VSAM Files
```

- **Cons:** Extra layer of infostructure (extra overheads, more to go wrong)
       More Coding

  May be worth considering for system with large system with very heavy usage.

  One Final point, Java has SQLJ, with SQLJ in DB2 the SQL is given to DB2 to store / maintain. 
  SQLJ has the same advantages as Sql-Procedures. I do not know of a .net equivalent though.